# Upgrade 17.10 to 18.04, now receiving login loop

Tags: upgrade, login, 18.04

After upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 I can't login. Each time I input password and click enter, I can see that GUI starts to load, but then kick me back out into login screen.
Only thing that I found for me to work for now is to click on a gear and pick Wayland Ubuntu. I guess this is not normal.

I checked .Xauthority and removed it.
I tried to reconfigure gdm3 and lightdm.
I also tried to look into sources.list to find bionic beaver resources, but don't really understand what should I look in there

Anyone experienced same problem? Where should I even start to look to try to debug this issue?

**Answer that worked for me**:
Before you enter user/password to log in into Ubuntu there is a gear icon should be available, next to "Sign In" button. Click on it and switch Wayland to Xorg, or vice-versa, for me this worked. Or fresh install...

Comment: What happened if you use `nomodeset` while booting to Ubuntu?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/nomodeset
I used this guide to set up nomodeset.  
It broke my boot completely.

Comment: It's strange, though.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Yes, before you enter user/password to log in into Ubuntu there is a gear icon should be available, next to "Sign In" button. Click on it and switch Wayland to Xorg, or vice-versa, for me this worked. Or fresh install...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. NVidia drivers were installed while I had AMD Radeon graphics card. So I logged in through <kbd>cltr</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> screen and purge NVidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge "nvidia*"
sudo update-alternatives --auto x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

Another working solution was to install xubuntu and choose it through gear button on login screen.